# Do NSOperationQueues always complete their queues before being deallocated?

Tags: swift, nsoperationqueue

I've been given the task to clean up some existing Swift code on our project which has just been converted to Swift 3.  However, I keep seeing this which looks suspect to me.

```
OperationQueue().addOperation(someOperation)
```

Here are the concerns/issues I have...

- The queue instance is created and used right there. No reference to it is stored for use elsewhere.
- Because of the above, there will only ever be one operation in the queue, so why use the queue at all?
- Since no one is holding a reference to the queue, under ARC, shouldn't it be instantly deallocated, and if so, what happens to the now-executing operation itself? Does it get interrupted, aborted or does it still complete?

Anyway, I'm wondering if I'm missing something or am unaware of a 'feature' of NSOperationQueue and NSOperations that make this code make sense.  Can anyone shed light on this, or do you agree this is bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this pattern too. I think it works like NSURLConnection: the NSOperationQueue "knows" it has a pending operation and doesn't allow itself to go out of existence immediately. Also keep in mind that an NSOperationQueue isn't really a "thing"; it's a kind of front for an underlying dispatch queue.

It makes a certain sense to use this pattern in situations where there is no reasonable place to store a reference to the queue. And you can use it to powerful effect, as in [this example](http://blog.krzyzanowskim.com/2015/11/25/code-at-the-end-of-the-queue/) where the operation has dependencies and thus is not executed until all the dependencies are.

Personally, however, if I'm not taking advantage of NSOperation features of that sort, I'd be more inclined to use GCD directly.

(As to your middle point, it would not make sense to execute on the main thread, because what if the operation is lengthy? You'd be blocking the main thread. However, do note that if all you're trying to say is "do this after everything else", Swift gives you `defer`.)

Comment: Regarding my point 2, I realized that mistake as soon as I posted it, but ran into a meeting.  Correcting it now...

Comment: The purpose of the queue is to get onto a background thread — which, as I said, under normal circumstances I'd do by using GCD directly. However, as I also said, NSOperation lets you do things you can't do using GCD alone, and in those situations I might use a pattern like this one. Bear in mind, too, that GCD is relatively new, whereas NSOperation has a much longer history, so this pattern may grow out of the dim past (just a guess).